# Switching on a type variable

Tags: c#, switch-statement, c#-7.0

This feels like it should be really easy, but I just can't see a way to get this to work.

```
Type propType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
switch (propType)
{
  case typeof(byte): // Can't do this, 'A constant value is expected'
    // Do something
    break;
}
```

I also tried doing

```
private const byteType = typeof(byte);
```

and switching on that, but this line of code fails to compile for the same reason.

So, the question: How do I switch on an instance of `Type`?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't want to use if/else?

Comment: Does that matter to the question? @Orangesandlemons

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment, but when you have about 12 `else if`'s, you start thinking maybe this should be a switch.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, my initial answer was wrong. You can't do that in a type switch (without using `when` as pointed out, which is awful for this use in my opinion). The problem is that a `Type` is not a constant, so you can't use that in a switch.

I was mistaken because you weren't using the actual value but a `Type` instance. You have to keep using `if` statements.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Compiler fails with 'An expression of type Type cannot be handled by a pattern of type byte.'

Comment: Well, it did give me one idea, which works, but... `case Type t where t == typeof(byte)`, but I kind of feel this isn't really giving any real benefit over a dozen if/else statements.

Comment: Nah, indeed. Not that pretty. A dictionary might be useful to reduce code repetition.

Comment: I still don't understand why `typeof(byte)` isn't considered a constant. Or `typeof(anything)` for that matter.

Comment: Because class instances can't be constant. @Flynn1179

Comment: @DannyChen `null` isn't an instance. It is the lack of an instance.

Comment: There is no good way to do this. Using `when` as in your answer is worse than a clear `if` statement in my opinion. But let's agree to disagree :) .

Comment: @DavidArno Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `switch`, you just need to use a `var` pattern and `when` guard:

```
Type propType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
switch (propType)
{
    case var b when b == typeof(byte):
        // Do something
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are set on using `switch` on `Type`, I think you have few choices, both fairly poor.

The first option is to use `TypeCode`, e.g.:

```
switch (Type.GetTypeCode(propType))
{
  case TypeCode.Byte:
    // Do something
    break;
}
```

This approach is severely limited, since it supports only the few built-in types that are in [the `TypeCode` enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.typecode(v=vs.110).aspx).

Another option is to switch on the type name:

```
switch (propType.FullName)
{
  case "System.Byte":
    // Do something
    break;
}
```

This is not great either, since you have to write the full name including namespace, the name is not checked for typos and such `switch` would also accept "fake" `System.Byte` type (i.e. a custom type named `System.Byte`, not the one included in .Net).

Comment: @downvoter What do you think is wrong with this answer?